# Angular Material Mat-Table datatable is not rending data from nested objects

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am writing an angular material mat-table with a datasource but it is not rending any data

Here is my data type

```
interface IProfile {
  jobTitle: string;
  startDate: string;
  endDate: string;
}
interface IAddress {
  name: string;
  address: string:
  city: string;
  state: string;
  country: string;
  county: string;
  zipcode: string;
}

interface IEmployee {
  profile: IProfile;
  address: IAddress[];
}

dataSource : MatTableDataSource<IEmployee >;
dataSource.data = this.testData;

this.myData: IEmployee[]= [] ;
    this.myData.push = [{ profile: this.testProfileData, address: this.testAddressData}];
this.datasource.data = this.myData;
```

In intellisense, I see the following content of myData

0: Object { Address: Array(21); Profile: Object }

Everything here is fine. I see the populated profile object and address array in the object after the datasource binding.

In my HTML code

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort multiTemplateDataRows class="mat-elevation-z8" width="100%">

        <ng-container matColumnDef="name" >
          <th mat-header-cell class="table-header" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header><h3>Address</h3></th>
          <td mat-cell style="width: 15%;" *matCellDef="let myData">{{myData.address.name}}</td>
        </ng-container>
```

When the UI is loading, the table is empty

I tried changing the code to the following since myData is has only 1 record with the profile object and address array

```
<td mat-cell style="width: 15%;" *matCellDef="let myData">{{myData.address[0].name}}</td>
```

But this only shows 1 value on the table. I have not gotten the UI to render all the name values in the array.

Any help is appreciated.

Update: I finally got it to populate. Is this the best approach

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name" >
      <th mat-header-cell class="table-header" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header><h3>Name</h3></th>
      <div *matCellDef="let myData">
        <div *ngFor="let metric of myData.address">
          <td mat-cell style="width: 15%;" >{{address.name}}</td>
        </div>
       </div>
    </ng-container>
```

Comment: Please either create a StackBlitz or provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Explain how you need to display address data in table as comma separated values or as a nested table.

Comment: Hi Harshana, I just updated my updated code with additional DIV tags to add *ngFor. Was wondering if this is the best approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this usage is not correct and you should see undefined errors in your console

```
<td mat-cell style="width: 15%;" *matCellDef="let myData">{{myData.address.name}}</td>
```

because `myData.address` is an array and there is no `name` property on it.

whereas,

```
<td mat-cell style="width: 15%;" *matCellDef="let myData">{{myData.address[0].name}}</td>
```

this is correct but it normally displays only the first address name because you are referencing only the first item in `address` array.

what you need to do is iterate over `myData.address` with `*ngFor` in order to display all adresses;

```
<td mat-cell style="width: 15%;" *matCellDef="let myData">
  <div *ngFor="let addr of myData.address">{{ addr.name }}</div>
</td>
```